# How do I know if the mouse position is within the maximum base area of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few DIV tags within my HTML page. The DIVs are positioned as absolute and some overlap each other on the page. If I click within the area of DIVs, it is possible that there might be more than one DIV overlapping in that position.

I am aware on how to capture the mouse position within the DIV through the **offset** property but I also need to know the DIV nearest to whose base the mouse pointer is lying. Is there any way to get the position of a mouse pointer relative to a rectangular base of a DIV?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Hi you can get the offsetX and Y and do something like if mouse cursor inside div then its close to X div

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I get the mouse pointer, I guess I can identify the offset left and top; and then calculate the relative position from the DIVs using the DIV's offset property. But how do I know whether it is within one DIV or more than one DIV and nearest to which DIV's base? 

Appreciate if you can please post some code

Comment: You work it out by say if mousex > div.offsettop and mousex < div.offsetx. Div could refer to a single div or an array of divs. you could then say that the rule is they are near by ten pixels so you would have a test to see what div they are in and then similar code but instead of the full height of the nearest divs you say 10px. Something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would try this out. The other problem is that the rectangular DIVs are all rotated by 36 degrees each to form a piechart like structure. Hence, trying to check mouseX against the DIV left or top would not work in a few cases. Just wondering how could I identify the proper DIV even if it is more than 90 or 180 degrees rotated anticlockwise.